# Duplicate Local Variable Intent However Service Class Requires 2 Intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service

I can't resolve an issue with a duplicate local variable in my service class. Our goal is to create a script which continually monitors the android history until it finds a match - then executes a warning class if the service class finds a match in the browser history. The issue occurs when attempting to execute our warning class - eclipse is stating we have a duplicate local variable "intent" however we need to keep it in order to launch our warning class. If we we remove our initial intent - the service will not start. If we remove the 2nd intent - our warning class will not start. (It's a bit of a catch 22 - since we need to launch/execute both).

```
public class Service_class extends Service {
    String Dirty1 = "www.pornhub.com";
    String Dirty2 = "www.playboy.com";
    String Dirty3 = "www.penthouse.com";
    String Dirty4 = "www.playboy.com";
    String Dirty5 = "www.playboy.com";
    String Dirty6 = "www.playboy.com";
    String Dirty7 = "www.playboy.com";
    String Dirty8 = "www.playboy.com";
    String Dirty9 = "www.playboy.com";
    String Dirty10 = "www.playboy.com";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.main3);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
        String[] projection = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE,
        Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
                projection, null, null, null);
        String urls = "";
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String url1 = null;
        String url2 = null;
        do {
        String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));

        if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty1)) {
        } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty2)) {
        } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty3)) {
        } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty4)) {
        } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty5)) {
        } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty6)) {
        } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty7)) {
        } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty8)) {
        } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty9)) {
        } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty10)) {
        //if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Filthy)) {
        urls = urls
        + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE)) + " : "
        + url + "\n";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Service_class.this, Warning.class);
        Service_class.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext()); 
     //   tv.setText(urls);




        return START_STICKY;

        }}
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
    private void setContentView(int main3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private TextView findViewById(int hello) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private Cursor managedQuery(Uri bookmarksUri, String[] projection,
            Object object, Object object2, Object object3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just rename your local variable of `intent` to a different name instead of using the function's parameter name?

```
Intent warning_intent = new Intent(Service_class.this, Warning.class);
Service_class.this.startActivity(warning_intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Intent intent` is declared as a parameter to `onStartCommand` and then you try to declare it again inside the method.  Just rename the second declaration of `intent` to `intent2` or something..

Also, it looks like you're monitoring *bookmarks* and not the browser *history*.  Might want to look into that.